# Account for overrotation of imaginary argument in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, math

Let's say we have some Fourier transform with an imaginary and real part.
Calculating the magnitude for some frequency is simple as shown in the code below.

However if the frequency, in this case `p=1`, is for example `1000` then we have an issue. We need to account for the fact that the imaginary part has to be in between `-pi` and `pi`.

For example. Let's say that my imaginary part is `Im => w-100` and my real part is just `Re => 1`.

The angle/phase would be: `arctan(Im/Re) = arctan(w-100)`. Simply substituting a value for `w` will not work. We need to subtract the extraneous full rotations and pass that to the `arctan` function.

How would I do that?

```
p = 1; % Value given in argument

x1 = exp(-4*(t-2))*cos(9*t)*heaviside(t); % define function
F = fourier(x1,t,w); % fourier transformation
sub1 = double(subs(F,w,p)); % SUBSTITUTE value for omega

mod1 = abs(sub1) % print out modulus
ang1 = angle(sub1) % print out phase angle
```

NOTE: The fourier transform returns a symbolic function. Hence I'm casting it to a double in `sub1`.

Comment: Sorry for the previous answer, I added a numerical solution, not symbolic one, should have noted that.

Comment: @brodroll so no idea then? :p

Comment: I have little experience with Matlab's symbolic operations. Idk if the **atan2** function would work for your phase angle, nor have a way to test atm :x

Comment: atan2 is a 4 quadrant arc tangent (looks at sign of both x and y). That would seem to get you the correct phase. Extra full rotations of multiples of 2pi would not affect the numerical value of the imaginary part of the result

Comment: @hiandbaii if you substitute `p=inf` the value would be `pi/2` for the angle. This is theoretically speaking, not sure if matlab can handle inf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unwrap.html) function, which works under some cases very well :)... I've used it several cases for resolving Fourier Spectrums with a nice "unwrapped" phase :D:D:

```
ang2=unwrap(ang1);
```

If this do not work, try to pre-multiply after and before to fit in the `pi` fractions....

**EDIT**

Are you needing *this*?:

```
% Fourier Transform
syms t v;
w=(0:1:100*pi)';
lw=length(w);
x = exp(-4*(t-2))*cos(9*t)*heaviside(t); % Function
F = fourier(x,t,v); % Fourier Transform
F0= double(subs(F,v,w)); % Symbolic Substitution
f = abs(F0); %  Magnitude
th = angle(F0); % Phase (unwrap not required)
%th=unwrap(angle(F0)); % Unwrapped Phase

% Plot
ha=plotyy(w,f,w,th);
title('Fourier Transform');
xlabel('Frequency - \omega');
ylabel(ha(1),'Magnitude - |f|');
ylabel(ha(2),'Phase - \theta');
```

If so, no unwrapping of the phase is required, which smoothy varies from `pi/2` at `w=-inf` to `-pi/2` at `w=inf`....

[image]